# Can't download MRInstruments

Tags: r, github, package

I'm super new to all of this so please excuse any mistakes in my terminology. I'm trying to install the MRInstruments package in R using the following-

install_github("MRCIEU/MRInstruments")

But i am getting this message-

Skipping install of 'MRInstruments' from a github remote, the SHA1 (efa2ca0d) has not changed since last install.
Use `force = TRUE` to force installation

I've tried doing as it says and using force = TRUE to force the installation but it just creates a value in the environment and still doesn't install.

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing from Github using `devtools()`,

```
devtools::install_github("MRCIEU/MRInstruments")
```

And got no errors. Try uninstalling the package, and re-install it and see what happens.

```
remove.packages("MRInstruments"); 
devtools::install_github("MRCIEU/MRInstruments")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried this and it did look like it was working but then came back with the following- Error: Failed to install 'MRInstruments' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘MRInstruments’ is in use and will not be installed

Comment: So you removed it, and re-installed it - and it still doesn't work? Interesting. Can you post you `session.info()` please!